# Macro Code to delete rows untill defined column

Tags: excel, vba

How do I limit a Macro to function only within certain range let's say until certain column?

I have a case where macro needs to delete the rows based on condition. I also want to put some instructions on the right and a form control button for macro but it seems like every time the code is activated, it deletes everything in that row, including the instructions and button I made. So I want to define a range where macro should be active.

I have following logic active.

1. First flag the item to be checked.
2. In loop, keep checking and deleting the rows.
3. Delete the rows based on an extra condition.

The code is working fine, but I want to add limitation until certain column like said.

Where do i define the range? In three separate logic, or at once on top?
Any help would be appreciated.

BR,

Manny

Comment: if you delete a row, the whole row will be deleted. That's what deleting a row does. Please take the [tour], learn [ask] and then edit your question and provide the code you have. Then we can help improve it.

Comment: Thank you all, i came across a solution that worked for me. Unfortunately due to some reason i could not elaborate my issue more, but your response on the topic is highly appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have told your code to delete the entire row. If you only want the macro to delete the data in columns A to G, for example, then use code along the lines of

```
Range("A" & rownumber & ":G" & rownumber).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace the line of code that deletes the whole row with code that deletes only set range. So for example instead of

```
Rows("12:12").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

you will have

```
Range("A12:N12").Delete Shift:=xlUp
```